# How to add a title to a ggplot when the title is a variable name?

Tags: r, ggplot2, title

At the end of a ggplot, this works fine:

```
+ opts(title = expression("Chart chart_title..."))
```

But this does not:

```
chart_title = "foo"
+ opts(title = expression(chart_title))
```

nor this:

```
chart_title = "foo"
+ opts(title = chart_title)
```

How can I add a title to a ggplot when the title is a variable name?

Comment: I'm confused, the following works just fine for me:

> meow <- "meow"
> qplot(rnorm(100), rnorm(100)) + opts(title = meow)

Comment: 'opts' is deprecated. Use 'theme' instead.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As others pointed out, your example seems to work fine for the cases where the variable chart_title is a string or an expression.  Sometimes it's tricky to construct the title variable; for instance, a confusing scenario might arise if chart_title uses some other variables, and if in addition you are using some greek characters so a simple `paste(...)` doesn't suffice.  To construct a title like that, you could use something like the following:

```
foo <- rnorm(100)
number <- 1
chart_title <- substitute(paste("Chart no. ",number,": ",alpha," vs ",beta,sep=""), list(number = number))
qplot(foo,foo) + opts(title = chart_title)
```

Another function that comes in handy when constructing titles is `bquote()`.  Programmatic title construction can be a messy business; R FAQ 7.13 ([http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-substitute-into-a-plot-label_003f)) can get you started, but even that FAQ basically tells you to search R-Help when in doubt.

Comment: Strange... I think it was a hidden carriage return at the end o the line ( I need to change text editor!) Many thanks.

Answer (score 30):

Opts is being deprecated. One option is to use labs()

```
myTitle <- "My title"
qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars) + labs(title = myTitle)
```

Pretty much the same.

Answer (score 15):

Please provide a reproducible example.  The following works fine for me:

```
title <- "My title"
qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars) + opts(title = title)
```

Since version 0.9.2, `opts` has been [replace](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/theme.html) by `theme`:

```
qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars) + theme(title = title)
```

Also, see `?ggtitle`.

Answer (score 4):

```
ggtitle( paste( "The sum is =", mysum, "The Count is =", N ) )
```

mysum and N are variables