# Ggplot2 and incrementing numbers in titles of a series of plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

When you create a series of plots with `ggplot2`, how can you programmatically add a number in the plot title to show which plot it is in the series?  The examples below have Plot 1, Plot 2 and Plot 3 hard coded in the title; how can ggplot put in 1, 2, 3, etc.?  The plots will be inserted in a document at different places.

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = seq(1:10), var2 = seq(3:12))
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = var1, y = var2)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("Plot 1")
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = var1, y = var2)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("Plot 2")
p3 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = var1, y = var2)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("Plot 3")
```

http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-substitute-into-a-plot-label_003f addresses variables and expressions but I need some kind of incremental counter.
[How to add a title to a ggplot when the title is a variable name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359723/how-to-add-a-title-to-a-ggplot-when-the-title-is-a-variable-name) doesn't seem to help

Is something like the following possible?

```
plot_counter <- 1
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = var1, y = var2)) + geom_point() + ggtitle(paste("Plot",  plot_counter + 1")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I get what you are trying to do. This does what I understood from your question:

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = seq(1:10), var2 = seq(3:12))
i <- 0
library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = var1, y = var2)) + geom_point() + 
         ggtitle(paste("Plot", i <- i+1))
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = var1, y = var2)) + geom_point() + 
         ggtitle(paste("Plot", i <- i+1))
p3 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = var1, y = var2)) + geom_point() + 
         ggtitle(paste("Plot", i <- i+1))

print(p1)
print(p2)
print(p3)
```

Are you using knitr? That might change the answer.

Comment: That is perfect!  As usual, once the answer is provided I slap my forehead and wonder why I didn't think of it.  I will wait a bit, @Roland, in case someone else suggests an alternative or improvement.

Comment: I am not using knitr because the whole pandoc step to produce Word documents was too cumbersome.  I use the ReporteRs package which is easier for me.