# Map ggplot2 title to a variable in a dlply call

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations

```
set.seed(8)    
df <- data.frame(
      v1 = rep(c("A","B","C"),25),
      v2 = runif(75,0,2),
      v3 = sample(c("cat1", "cat2", "cat3"), 75, replace=T))
```

Plot three plots in a `d_ply()` (or `dlply()`), splitting over `v3`

```
require(plyr)
    d_ply(df, .(v3), .print=T, function(x){
    ggplot(x,aes(v1, v2)) +
    geom_point()})
```

How do I specify some annotation using variables (legends, titles). For instance the title of each plot should be mapped to the `v3` variable. With reference to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359723/how-to-add-a-title-to-a-ggplot-when-the-title-is-a-variable-name) this doesn't work for me:

```
d_ply(df, .(v3), .print=T, function(x){
    ggplot(x,aes(v1, v2)) + 
    theme(title=v3) +
    geom_point()})
```

Nor does theme(title=unique(v3)). Maybe it is something about have I access `v3`in `d_lpy()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ggtitle` and not just `v3`, but `x$v3`.

```
d_ply(df, .(v3), .print=T, function(x){
  ggplot(x,aes(v1, v2)) + 
    ggtitle(x$v3) +
    geom_point()})
```